# How can I avoid alt text in Chrome from displaying incorrectly?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So this problem is kind of hard to explain... In an AngularJS template I'm working on, two images are loaded fairly close to one another. Each image represents the logo for a sports team. The alt text for each logo is its "short name" (e.g., "New England" for the New England Patriots). When trying to read the alt text for one logo, it will display with no problems. However, when trying to read the alt text for the other logo after having done so, the previous logo's alt text will be displayed for a split second before being replaced by the current logo. This problem occurs even if the mouse hovers elsewhere in between logos.

I have absolutely no idea why this would occur, as the images do not overlap. Moreover, this problem seems to only occur in Chrome.

Any ideas as to what might be the cause/solution?

~~~ Edit ~ ~ ~

One thing to note is that this problem seems to be  more defined when working on a virtual machine. When trying to replicate it on a local machine, the glitch is barely perceptible.

Also, the HTML code (kinda) looks like this:

```
<!-- code -->
<th scope="col" class="some-wrapper-class"><img class="small-logo" data-ng-src="{{refToTeam1ImgURL}}" alt="{{refToTeam1Name}}" title="{{refToTeam1Name}}"><span class="team-name">{{refToTeam1Name}}</span></th>
<!-- Another similar line of code for team 2 -->
```

Comment: it would help to see your html and css code

Comment: Hm... Well I can't really post any code because that stuff's classified yo. I can add more info, though.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean specifically with "When trying to read the alt text for one logo, it will display"... ? How exactly are you trying to read the alt text?

Comment: When I hover the mouse over a logo for the first time after loading the page, the alt text displays as it should.

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding correctly, but typically the `title` is what is going to show up when you hover over the image, not the alt text. Yours just happen to be the same. Perhaps you could remove the `title` attribute and try to style the tooltip another way, e.g., with a span that displays on hover?

Comment: Crap; I forgot to follow up on your comment and now I don't have access to the source code any more!